# Setting UIButton background image causes memory crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

UPDATE:
More or less solved. Tried the simplest possible solution (last, of course) and simply replaced the image with another one. Sure enough, no crash. Still very curious as to what's causing this. But at least I know I can fix it by simply subbing in another image. The one I was using was downloaded from a clip art site and modified in inkScape…maybe it's corrupted somehow. I may never know, but appreciate any insight!

I've never encountered this, I've tried three approaches (detailed below) and am a little stumped. I've tested on two different devices with the same result.

I have a view that loads from nib, containing an image view with a regular ole UIButton as a subview. Every time I set that button's background image, as soon as the parent view loads I get memory warnings. When I then tap the button, I crash (or rather, iOS kills me) due to memory pressure. When I don't set the image, everything runs fine.

I've tried:
1. Simply setting the image in the nib.
2. In the parent's viewWillAppear, setting the image like so:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowPencil.png"]
 forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

3. Alternatively, setting the image like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"yellowPencil" ofType: @"png"];
UIImage *pencil = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
[button setBackgroundImage:pencil forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Methods 1 and 2 generated repetitive memory warnings, as though something was looping, and crash when I tap the button.

Method 3 consistently generates two warnings, and crashes due to memory pressure when I tap the button.

Again, leaving the image out of the equation solves the problem. The image is a PNG that I created in inkScape and is the correct size, with an @2x version.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: How large is your png?

Comment: 44x44pts. File size is was 26kb for the @2x, just a few kb for the smaller one.

Comment: I see you solved the problem. Yes, I agree it seems like the file was corrupt and not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use jpeg if you don't need the alpha channel.

Comment: Hmm...I've always read that png is the preferred format for iOS. I am using the alpha channel to animate opacity, though. Thanks for the tip anyway!